Why free disposal assumption needed in Prop 5.C.1 and 5.C.2 in MWG?
I'm a little confused as why we needs only the assumption of Y being closed and satisfies free disposal in the MWG prop 5.C.1 and 5.C.2. I think i know why Y needs to be closed but what about free disposal? I am missing something? Thanks!

Could you please make your question self-contained?
